# How to unselect modules in CLI installation

Tags: magento2, installation, cli, install-script

When installing through the web UI wizard, you're given the option to not install certain modules (`Customize your store -> Advanced Modules Configurations`). Can the same be done with the CLI installer?

**NOTE:**
I am aware of module:disable.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any option to remove specific modules during installation through cli , you can confirm it from following devdoc link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html.

But you can uninstall those modules after installation.You can read about it in following link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

Comment: I suspect that **--magento-init-params** could be used for this, but the documentation for it is pretty minimal.